# Как сделать так, чтобы бот ждал ответа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Есть код бота ВК.

```
import vk_api, json
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from narmon import *
from sinoptik import *
from data import *

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = "")
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def get_but(text, color):
    return {
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "payload": "{\"button\": \"" + "1" + "\"}",
                    "label": f"{text}"
                },
                "color": f"{color}"
            }
 
keyboard = {
    "one_time" : False,
    "buttons" : [
        [get_but('Время', 'primary'), get_but('Погода', 'primary')],
        [get_but('Дата', 'primary'), get_but('Помощь', 'primary')] 
    ]
}
keyboard = json.dumps(keyboard, ensure_ascii = False).encode('utf-8')
keyboard = str(keyboard.decode('utf-8'))

def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0, 'keyboard' : keyboard})

def function(): 
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me:

                    msg = event.text.lower()
                    id = event.user_id

                    if msg == 'начать':
                        sender(id, 'Привет. Для того, чтобы узнать список команд, напиши "Помощь".')
                    elif msg == 'привет':
                        sender(id, 'Привет. Для того, чтобы узнать список команд, напиши "Помощь".')
                    elif msg == 'помощь':
                        sender(id, 'Список команд:\n\n❓Помощь - Выводит список команд.\n⛅Погода - Выводит погоду на сегоднящний день.\n⌚Время - Выводит точное время.\nДата - Выводит текущую дату.')
                    elif msg == 'погода':
                        items = parse()
                        temp = update_temp()
                        sender(id, 'Температура: ' + str(temp) + '°C\n' + items)
                    elif msg == 'время':
                        time = update_time()
                        sender(id, 'Точное время: ' + str(time) + '.')
                    elif msg == 'дата':
                        day = update_date()
                        weekday = update_weekday()
                        month = update_month()
                        sender(id, 'Сегодня: ' + weekday + ', ' + str(day) + ' ' + month + '.')
                    elif msg == 'предложить новость':
                        sender(id, 'Следущим сообщением напишите новость.')

                    else:
                        sender(id, 'Команда нераспознана.')
    except:
        function()
function()
```

В нем присутствует функция для отправки сообщений sender. Также есть условия если новое сообщение отправлено боту с командой "предложить новость". То он должен ответить "введите следующим сообщение новость". Вопрос в том, как задержать бота, чтобы он ждал это самое сообщение?

Answer (score 1):

На основе вашего кода, попробуйте прописать так:

```
elif msg == 'предложить новость':
    sender(id, 'Следущим сообщением напишите новость.') 
    from_id = event.user_id()
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.user_id == from_id: 
                #дальше ваш код
```

Минусом такого кода будет то, что пока не введут сообщение с предложкой, он будет ждать и не сможет отвечать на другие команды